# Can GUIDE access the command window?

Tags: matlab

I wanted to click a button in a plugin designed by GUIDE and copy the last command in the command history from the command window to the plugin. Is it possible?

Comment: All the command history goes into a file (look up Mathworks for its location). It would be easier to read the last line(s) of the file instead of trying to hack the command window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to read from the history file

```
fullfile ( prefdir, 'History.xml' )
```

or to use undocumented hacks (works in r2015b):

```
allHistory = com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
historyText = char(allHistory);
lastLine = strtrim(historyText(end,:));
```